# getElementByID in a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing some VBA code which manipulates an HTML document.  The document is opened as text so that the HTML can be worked on.  Thus:

```
Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document
Set oWordDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFileName, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatText)
```

The HTML contains some meta tags that I would like to be able to access by ID.  This is the code I tried to attempt this:

```
Dim objHtmlDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objMetaTag As HTMLMetaElement
Set objHtmlDoc = oWordDoc
Set objMetaTag = objHtmlDoc.getElementById("keywords")
```

However, I get a Type Mismatch error on the line:

```
Set objHtmlDoc = oWordDoc
```

I tried to set the objHtmlDoc to oWordDoc.content, and get the same error.  Is there anyway that I can convert the Word.Document object to an HTMLDocument object so that I can set the HTMLDocument to be the Word.Document?  Or will I have to develop my own getElementbyID function to perform this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you open for an alternative?

Comment: Are you restricted to VBA/VBScript? It's hardly suitable for your task.

Comment: It's the tool I've been given to work with.  I may be able to get away with using something else.  What do you suggest?

Comment: If you open an HTML file as text in Word, you don't get an HTMLDocument, just plain text. Siddharth's approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Alternative that I was suggesting.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objHtmlDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim objMetaTag As HTMLMetaElement
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "C:\Sample.Htm"

    Set objHtmlDoc = IE.Document
    Set objMetaTag = objHtmlDoc.getElementById("keywords")
End Sub
```